# Automatically georeference hundreds of png files based on polygon vector coordinates

Tags: georeferencing, png

I have 1000 polygons in my shapefile. I also have 1000 PNG files. Do you think it is possible (based on a common attribute), through a script or something, to assign each of those PNG files to a polygon? I am looking for an automated process which should "read" the polygon coordinates and based on that common attribute, it should somehow take the corresponding PNG, transform it in a tiff file and place it between the boundaries of that polygon? Basically, do the georeferencing for me ...

I use mostly open source software and Global Mapper but I have no clue on how to do this..

Many thanks for the support,

Comment: Even if your polygon has same aspect ratio as the corresponding image, how will you assure its rotation won't be off by 180 degrees?

Comment: Hello Kirk,

My desire is to stretch the png to the bounds of the polygon so it would fit exactly within the bounds. If it rotates the image 180 degrees, well, that is no problem. I just want to find a way to replace the manual geoeferencing of 1000 images in order to speed up the process.
Honestly, I do not know how to do this..I appreciate any advice

Comment: When you are manually doing this, how do you verify that the image's rotation isn't off by 180 degrees?

Comment: If the polygons have the name of the PNG file as attribute, some script lines should do the job (GRASS or GDAL). Otherwise, how to related polygons and PNG positions to each other?

Comment: Hello Markus,

Yes, the polygons have a unique ID in the attribute table and the png files have the names similar with the unique ID to which they correspond.. so, there are 1000 polygones, each of them with a unique ID and also, 1000 png's, all of the latter named with those 1000 unique ID's; :)

Comment: Could you provide a part of that shp file and few png?

Comment: @MarioMiler

Hello,

I rapidly took 3 polygons and 3 png files .. the coomon link between them is: polyid in the attribute table = png names

http://www.mediafire.com/?7g5ygla0fxh7l75

The png files are downloaded randomly from google.

Let me know if it works,

Many thanks

Comment: Just as I thought, problem is with vertex order. There is not rule, for example, I can not say that every first vertex of every polygon is always lower left corner of png image or any other similar rule. That complicates things. It could probably be done with python and GDAL/OGR but you would need lot of IF's or you could calculate centroid of that polygon and assign rotation angle to that centroid and then somehow calculate image rotation and position based on that centroid. That is just a quick thought.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Python to script a solution. I'd try to georeference the png corners to the corresponding polygon envelope or bounding rectangle corners. This can be accomplished with gdal_translate -gcp and gdal_warp. The resulting shape image in the geotiff may not perfectly overlay the polygon shape, but should be close.

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall:
Well, the image is a label (let's say, it contains the word GEO on a blue background), if I manually assign the coordinates for 4 points (the corners of the image) I know exactely how it is going to show up on my map because I already have the polygon from where I took the coordinates and it will fit right inside. Does this make sense, am I missing something in your question? Sorry if yes,

@ klewis
Thank you very much, I will try this, maybe something good happens :)